# Get checkbox state from localstorage

Tags: javascript, checkbox, local-storage

I already have the state of a checkbox located in 1.html stored in localStorage (can be checked or unchecked).

In a diffrent document, 2.html, using vanilla javascript how can I know if the checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Tryied this, no luck:

```
if localStorage.getElementById("my_checkbox").checked {
    alert("checked") ;
}
```

and

```
if localStorage.getItem("my_checkbox").checked {
    alert("checked") ;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage only stores string values, so you would first need to fetch it:

```
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('myCheckbox');
```

then figure out whether if the value `true` was saved:

```
if(storedValue /* need to check for undefined */ && storedValue === 'true'){
    alert('checked');
}
```

However, I would recommend storing a stringified object and parse it rather than dealing with strings. Something like this should get you started:

```
// set data:
var lsData = {};
lsData.myCheckbox = documnent.getElementById("my_checkbox").checked;
var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(lsData);

localStorage.setItem('lsData', stringifiedData);
```

```
// get data:
var dataToParse = localStorage.getItem('lsData');
if(dataToParse){
    var lsData = JSON.parse(dataToParse);
    alert(lsData.myCheckbox);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Working on it!

Comment: @user3002057 Any time

Comment: Still can't make it work. Please see the fiddle. I should get an alert when the checkbox is checked, no?

Comment: @user3002057 For starters, you misspelled `document`. Check the console :) Also, it will always be false here, since you do the save at the page load, before you have a change to change it.

Comment: @user3002057 Maybe this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/ck0eph8z/1/ It updates localStorage when you click the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you Johan, will surley get it to work from here.